# setCenter in Libgdx not available in nightlies package, and setOrigin not working well?

Tags: java, position, libgdx, sprite

I would like to change the center point of my image, the position (in the world) works fine, but not the center point (in the sprite), the link for the Sprite API : 
[http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setOriginCenter()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setOriginCenter%28%29)

only setOrigin is available in the methods for a Sprite, and changing it with -100,-100 or 0,0  does not change anything. Would anyone know why?

```
sprite = new Sprite(tex);
sprite.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
sprite.setOrigin(-100,-100);//(sprite.getWidth()*0.5f, sprite.getHeight()*0.5f);//(0,0);
sprite.setSize(0.5f, 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `setOrigin` you set the `origin` of the `Sprite`, which is responsible for `rotation` and `scaling`. But it does not affect the `position`.
This means, that if you set the `origin` to `P(width/2,height/2)` and you rotate your `Sprite` it will rotate arround his center. If you set the `origin` to the left lower corner `P(0,0)` it will rotate arround that corner.
The `position` instead is always the left, lower corner and it is not affected by the `origin`.
If you want to hold a `position` as center point you need to recalculate the left lower corner out of that:

```
sprite.setPosition(posVector.x-sprite.getWidth()/2, posVector.y-sprite.getHeight()/2);
```

Note, that the `origin` is relative to the `Sprite`s `position`. So P(0,0) is the left lower corner and P(width,height) is the right upper corner.